# When deploying rabbitmq as statefull set how can I make it wait untill each node is ready

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq service running in kubernetes. Its deployed as a statefullset.

Lets say I have 3 nodes.

On node 1 and 2 I have a mirrored queue.

Then I start a deploy.
Kubernetes pulls down the first node and the second node starts to mirror with node 3 since node 1 is gone. But how can I prevent kubernetes from starting with node 2 untill it is done mirroring with the next node?

If its not done then I risk loosing messages.

Comment: 1) maybe use [Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) like here, in the [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/#statefulset)

Comment: 2) Please take a look here, [GCP RabbiMq click-to-deploy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/rabbitmq/README.md#solution-information).  This deployment applies an High Availability (HA) policy, which configures mirroring for all RabbitMQ nodes in the cluster, and automatically synchronizes with new mirrors that join the cluster. It is enabled as part of the installation, on each node's postStart event. Is that what you are looking for? Maybe you can install and see how exactly it works, then ajust for you..

Comment: Thx Vitalii. Ill take a look at it and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: Vitalii it is a really good link. But my main issue is not solved even by the google intsallation.